# New summation command with conditionals not working

Tags: macros, formatting, conditionals

I'm trying to create a summation command that formats it better than just using `\sum`, and without having to use `\sum\limits_a^b` every time. I'm using

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\summ}[3][\@nil]{%
\def\tmp{#1}%
\ifx\tmp\@nnil
   \sum\limits_{#2}^{#3}
\else
     \sum\limits_{#1 = #2}^{#3}
\fi}
\makeatother
```

The else part doesn't work. If I use `\summ{1}{2}`, I get

[image]

which is as expected. but if I use `\summ{1}{2}{3}`, I get

[image]

which is not right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: If I understand the definition of `\summ` correctly, it takes 3 arguments, the first of which is optional (and defaults to `\@nil`). If this understanding is correct, you may want to change `\summ{1}{2}{3}` to `\summ[i]{1}{2}`, say, as the first, optional parameter has to be encased in square brackets, *not* curly braces.

Comment: Also, you're comparing `\tmp` to `\@nnil` yet you're setting `\tmp` to `\@nil`. While they may be similar, other packages could define `\@nnil` at which point your macro would fail. So, make sure you're comparing `\tmp` to `\@nil` (what you're supplying in your default for the optional argument) and not something else.

Comment: why do you ever need `\sum\limits` ? if you want, for some reason `\sum` to take limits even in inline math just add `\limits` to its definition. But you basically then can not use `\sum` in inline math at all.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've set up the macro `\summ`, taking 1 optional and 2 required arguments, you probably shouldn't write `\summ{1}{2}{3}`; instead, do give `\summ[i]{1}{2}` a try. You'll find out that it expands to `\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2}`.

I think that defining `\summ` to take an optional argument is unnecessarily complicated. How about dropping the conditional and simply setting

```
\newcommand\summ[2]{\sum\limits_{#1}^{#2}}
```

That way, it's no big deal to switch from `\summ{1}{N}` to `\summ{i=1}{N}`, is it?

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\summ[2]{\sum\limits_{#1}^{#2}}
\begin{document}
$\summ{1}{N} \quad \summ{i=1}{N}$
\end{document}
```